# Firebase Web Authentication Not Working - Returning Error Only for Badly typed Email

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am facing an issue in firebase web-based authentication.
There is no error returning in the console from firebase, I purposefully tried different combinations of wrong password and email id but there is no error in logged in the console. By using correct login username(email) and password there is nothing showing and by stepping the code using chrome-dev-tools the function is not executing. can someone help? Thanks in Advance...

Given the javaScript code and HTML codes below could you please verify the code confirm something I missed??

But everything in android application working fine for this same Project

Added localhost in the domain under authentication and I am running the app in localhost.

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/userOperations.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form p-l-40 p-r-40 p-t-178">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        <img src="./img/logo.png">
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Please enter username">
                        <input class="input100" type="email" placeholder="Email" id = "username">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate = "Please enter password">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" placeholder="Password" id = "password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn ">
                        <button onclick="signIn()" class="login100-form-btn shadow">
                            LOGIN
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-right p-t-13 p-b-23">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            <a href="register_selection.html">
                            Register Now
                            </a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="txt2">
                            <a href="recover.html">
                            Forgot Password?
                            </a>
                        </span>

                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-col-c p-t-70 p-b-40">
                        <span class="txt4 p-b-9">
                            Copyright   &copy; 2019
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

firebase.js

```
<!-- language: lang-javascript -->

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
// added the required codes here
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  //Handle Account Status
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.alert("logged in");
  }
});

  const auth = firebase.auth();
  function signIn(){
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value; 
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;   
      console.log(username+password);

      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode+" "+errorMessage);
        // ...
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try-catch` and see

```
...

try {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
}
catch(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode+" "+errorMessage);
    // ...
}

...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply I tried this but still I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a Promise for which you should handle the two possible final states, either `resolve` with `.then()` (missing in your code) or `reject` with `.catch()` (which you do).

So, you are missing the `.then()` part where you would typically get user data and/or redirect to another page...

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. Changed the code like this 
   ` firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
      .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        window.alert("logged in ");
          // Success 
      })
     .catch(function(error) {
          // Error Handling
          window.alert("got errr");
     }); `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Suggestions and solutions bu I solved this issue by changing the `form class` to `div` in `HTML` file